# Regex for version number validaqtion

Tags: regex

I'm trying to build a regular expressions that will validated my version numbers from user input. The format is xx.yy.zzz and the allowed values are:

xx = 1-6,11,12,22

yy and zzz = any (0-9) combinations.

I came up with something list this:

```
([1-6]|[11-12]|[22])+(.[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9][0-9])$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/WejLPCDTgePC3JOx)

But it still allows digits before the xx. For example: 4444444444444444.15.142 is acceptable input but it should not be. Please help.

Comment: `[11-12]` is a Character class that matches any one character `1`,`-`and `2`

Comment: Need to escape `.` as well.

Comment: You can use this `^([1-6]+|11|12|22)\.([0-9]{2})\.([0-9]{3})$` [Check it](http://regex101.com/r/vD9aJ4/2)

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify what you mean that "4444444444444444.15.142 is acceptable input". Is that a valid version number? It doesn't match the allowed values for xx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need this:

`^([1-6]|11|12|22)\.\d{2}\.\d{3}$`

You didn't specify the beginning (^) and ending ($) anchors to match the entire string. Also, your character classes like `[11-12]` and `[22]` don't do what you think. Each class specified with square brackets matches **one character**, so `[22]` just matches "2".

Also, you didn't escape the dots, so they are really matching **any character**, not just a dot.

Comment: I corrected my version it's xx.yy.zzz, so ^([1-6]|11|12|22)\.\d{2}\.\d{3}$ should work. THANKS!!

Comment: I would appreciate it if whoever downvoted my answer would speak up. What's the reason? Thanks.

Comment: Your answer doesn't provide a solution. [Check it out](http://regex101.com/r/vD9aJ4/1) However, I didn't downvote you (you may check my profile)

Comment: @hex494D49, your regex101 example shows that my regex does NOT match 4444444444444.15.142, which is the intended result. If you try something like 4.15.142, it matches.

Comment: I guess you didn't read the whole question; at some point it says: _For example: 4444444444444444.15.142 is acceptable input_

Comment: @hex494D49: the OP was unclear in his wording. I believe he meant that his regex was mistakenly treating that as acceptable. If you look at the allowed values for x, it's just 1-6,11,12,22.

Comment: You're right, the OP isn't clear and that's why I added a comment rather than an answer. But at the same time your answer is wrong according to above. As you might saw, I don't downvote, but at the same time it's sad when people upvote without reading even a single line.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are after:

```
^([1-6]|1[12]|22)\.[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,2}$
```

^ = start

(|) = or matching

[1-6] = 1-6, one time

1[12] = 11 or 12

22    = 22

\. = dot

[0-9]{1,2} = 0-9, once or twice